# Correct component to display String/Image pair as a list in Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to display a HashMap as a list (both the labels as Strings and the BufferedImages as images side by side) in my Jasper report. As far as I researched this could be done by sending the Collection as a datasource like:

```
Map<String, BufferedImage> legendMap = new HashMap<>();

//fill the HashMap with label/image pairs...

JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource((Collection<?>) legendMap);
selectedReport.getReportParameters().put("P_DS1", beanColDataSource);
```

But at that point I can't figure out what would be the corresponding report component to display the datasource. i.e When I try to create a *parameter* in the report it automatically ends up as a text field. Although what I need is some kind of a composite thing which displays the label and the related small image. Any help to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about using two elements: *textField* (for showing text) and *image* (for showing image)?

Comment: yes I considered that option too, though I wanted to know whether the forementioned possibility exists.

Comment: You can also try to use *htmlcomponent*

Comment: thank you. now going to check it. another question: how can I iterate a List of images and display them in your suggested way?

Comment: With help of field